# PayPal Website payment pro not sending email to merchant when purchased using credit card

Tags: e-commerce, paypal

We have implemented PayPal Website Payments pro. Everything seems to work like a charm.

But, my merchant ain't receiving the emails from Paypal when the user purchases the item using their CreditCard. But, when purchased with their PayPal account, the emails are coming through fine.

Is this the normal behavior? Or, is there something that I need to fix in my settings ?

Answer (score 1):

The seller account should get the normal email notification that they've received a PayPal payment, but no email would be sent to the buyer.  This is intentional because buyers who specifically request CC instead of PayPal might be upset if they start getting PayPal notifications.

When using Payments Pro it's generally left up to you to create and send your own email receipts/notifications.

That said, you mentioned here that it's your merchant account that's not receiving anything, which would typically be referring to the seller account.  If that's what's happening then I'd recommend calling PayPal support or submitting a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts and let them know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your inputs. I will check with the PayPal support team.